Proving Algebraic Isomorphisms
(This is my first time that I use this site.Feel free to point out any problems with my presentation or behaviour.Thanks for watching, commenting and criticising！)
This problem was encountered when I was doing an exercise and the description of the problem is as follows:
Let $K$ be a field and $A$ an $n$-dimensional $K$-algebra (i.e., $A$ is a ring, $A$ is also an $n$-dimensional $K$-linear space, and the multiplication of $A$ is $K$-bilinear). Suppose $(,): A \times A \to K$ is some non-degenerate bilinear function on $A$.
Proof:
(1) the following equation $(x,y) = (y,φ(x)) (x,y) ∈ A$ defines a $K$-linear homomorphism $φ : A \to A$
(2) Further, if $(,)$ satisfies the union law, i.e., for all $x,y,z∈A$, there are $(xy,z)=(x,yz)$ holds, then $φ:A \to A$ maintains the multiplication of $K$-algebras, i.e., $φ$ is a $K$-algebraic homomorphism.
My analysis of the problem is as follows, please feel free to correct me if I am wrong
For (1), we know that $φ$ is a $K$- linear homomorphism if and only if $φ$ is a bijection and it maintains addition and multiplication.
For $x_1\in A$ and $x_2\in A$,$(y,φ(x_1)+φ(x_2))=(x_1,y)+(x_2,y)=(x_1+x_2,y)=(y,φ(x_1+x_2))$
so I got for any $y\in A$,$(y,φ(x_1)+φ(x_2))=(y,φ(x_1+x_2))$,implies$φ(x_1)+φ(x_2)=φ(x_1+x_2)$
(my first question is here: Is the above conclusion correct? That is:Does a non-degenerate bilinear function have the following property: if $(x,y)=0$ for any $y$, then $x=0$ )
If that's right,I can finish the rest proof of (1) and (2)
There is an extra equation: What is the meaning of the multiplication of A is K-bilinear?In fact I don't seem to have used this condition in my proofs
THANKS FOR YOUR WATCHING!

Please use MathJax. Here is a
tutorial.

Please show your work; math.SE is here to help with your homework, not do it for you. Questions which consist only of isolated problem statements tend to be badly recieved on this site.

All-capitals sentences evoke shouting. Please avoid them.

There is a missing step: you must show $\varphi$ is well-defined. Specifically, show that there exists a unique homomorphism $\varphi$ such that $(x,y) = (y,\varphi(x))$
